# javac gives an error message , that it has been found

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javac

When I type `java -version` the following is returned :

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

but when I type `javac -version` I get the following message :

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
* openjdk-6-jdk
* ecj
* gcj-4.4-jdk
* gcj-4.6-jdk
* gcj-4.5-jdk
* openjdk-7-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Why is this ? What do I need to do to get rid of this ?

Comment: It seems you just installed the JRE and not the JDK... `javac` is not available in the JRE. Which packages did you install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed the java runtime environment (jre) which contains stuff to *execute* java programs, but not the java development kit (jdk) which contains stuff to *build* such applications, like the compiler. So install one of these packages, as the message tells you, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: JDK7 an be used to compile code for both Java6 and Java7, whereas JDK6 obviously won't compile code for Java7. Therefore choosing the more recent version is the safer choice in terms of successful compiles. Application stability might be a reason to use an older and more tested java version, so in the end the choice is yours.

Comment: I meant if the interpreter was 6 why should the compiler be 7 ?

Comment: The [openjdk-7-jdk package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/openjdk-7-jdk) will pull in [openjdk-7-jre](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/openjdk-7-jre) as a dependency, so then you'd have a Java 7 RE as well. You can then [set the default java version](http://askubuntu.com/a/121673/71738) to either one. But you are right, installing JDK6 will take less space on your disk and will avoid trouble due to version mismatches, so unless your code requires Java 7, that is perfectly all right as well.

Comment: @MvG - as you say, it CAN make a difference.  If you compile with a JVM at a newer version than your minimum target JRE, there are 2 potential problems.  1) You may generate bytecodes with a version that the older JRE doesn't support.  2) You risk not noticing dependencies on classes that don't exist on the older platform.  Both of these lead to runtime errors.  These issues can be addressed, but it is SIMPLER to use a JDK that matches your JRE.

Answer (score 1):

The `java` command executes a program that is already compiled to a .class file (Java bytecode), it's just the runtime environment.

`javac` is the Java compiler. It turns Java source code into Java bytecode (.class files).

The two are separate programs because a typical user only needs the runtime (`java`) but not `javac`.

You need to install one of the listed packages (preferably openjdk-6-jdk. since it will be compatible with your java installation).